# Catching all the exceptions in a nested try catch and concatenating to a string

Tags: c#, .net, exception, nested, try-catch

Working on a windows application that opens various exes and operates using SendKeys. Using try catch for each exe. All exceptions messages would be mailed to the user. Something like this

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log("start");
     try{
        #region "Process1"
        try
        {
            Log("Beginning Process1()");
            Process1();
            smtp("process 1 success");
            Log("Process1() completed");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogFile(ex.Message, "Process1()", 27, "Form1.cs");
        }
        #endregion 

        #region "Process2"
        try
        {
            Log("Starting Process2");
            Process2();
            smtp("process 2 success");
            Log("Process2 completed");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogFile(ex.Message, "Process2", 27, "Form1.cs");
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Process 3"
        try
        {
            Log("Starting Process3");
            Process3();
            smtp("Process 3 success");
            Log("Process3 completed");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionLogFile(ex.Message, "Process3", 61, "Form1.cs");
        }
        #endregion

       }
    catch(Exception ex)
     { 
      smtp(ex.Message);
      }
    }
```

The final catch block should essentially concatenate all the possible exceptions caught so that i could reduce the number of mails being triggered.

P.S. smtp() is the method im using to generate the mail. The parameter being passed is the body of the mail

```
public void Process1()
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("Process1");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;


        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
    }
```

Tab and enter are used to manipulate buttons in the window of Process1()

Comment: What's the problem ? Call `smtp(ex.Message)` in each catch block.

Comment: I think he should create a `StringBuilder` and in each `catch` block append the message from the exception and process name. At the end he would send the mail with the contents (if any) of the `StringBuilder` as message. If the processes are running asynchrons he would need different code.

Comment: Unless you rethrow the exception in each catch block, you won't enter the final catch block (with the smtp() call). But if you rethrow the exception, you won't get more than one exception.

Comment: @adnanumer calling smtp() in each catch block will send multiple mails which is what i want to avoid

Comment: @mortb the processes are all in running state once the process() method is called. So at any time any exe or multiple exes can throw exceptions. I want to ensure that in the extremely rare scenario that two exes throw exceptions at the same time both are caught.  how can string builder be used here? I'm not aware how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log("start");
    var exceptionList = new List<string>();
    RunProcess(Process1, "Process1", 27, exceptionList);
    RunProcess(Process2, "Process2", 27, exceptionList);
    RunProcess(Process3, "Process3", 61, exceptionList);

    smtp(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, exceptionList));
}

private void RunProcess(Action processAction, string processName, int processValue,
                        ICollection<string> exceptions)
{
    try
    {
        Log("Starting " + processName);
        processAction.Invoke();
        smtp(processName + " success");
        Log(processName + " completed");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ExceptionLogFile(e.Message, processName, processValue, "Form1.cs");
        exceptions.Add(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: process1() is just not a simple start line.It will operate the process using sendkeys. adding said code in question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "simple start line". If `Process1`, `Process2` etc are actual Windows processes (i.e. separate exes), then their runtime exceptions will not be caught by the catch block anyway. Only exceptions thrown when *starting* the process will be caught.